# HttpURLConnection outputstream chinese character

Tags: java, character, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I use HttpUrlConnection to post outside a json but seems Chinese characters are changing to ?????
I tried with different encoding style like utf-16,big 5 but I cant understand what is causing  this. 
When I debug this, I can see chineese character before post, but when post, it changes why?
 code parts is in the below

```
        String postData,String charset) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        URL url = new URL(targetUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(
                                                                Proxy.NO_PROXY);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(postTimeout);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                                    contentType+"; charset="+charset);//+charset.getName().toUpperCase());//+charset.getName());



        sleep(sleepTime);
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        //"UnicodeBigUnmarked"
//        
//        byte[] bt= postData.getBytes();
//        System.out.println(bt);
//        os.write(bt);
//        System.out.println();
//        os.flush();
        //System.out.println(postData);
        try
        {
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, charset);
            writer.write(postData);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.severe("Http POST exception");

        } finally {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }



       int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

       connection.disconnect();

       return responseCode;
```

I tried with big5,utf-16, but still no change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should use the unicode ascii-safe representation in JSon like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733931/java-string-unicode-value)