# Convert String to unicode?

Tags: java, string, parsing, unicode

How to convert Strings to unicode? Characters are easy. But if I have "C" stored as a String, how can convert it to unicode? Because for characters, you just can use (int)charvariable but how to do for strings?

Actually I am using String.split() to split a String and then want to check if the 1st character is capital or small. Integer.parseInt is not working. It says NumberFormatException.

Comment: possible duplicated [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733931/java-string-unicode-value)

Comment: What do you mean "convert to unicode"? Strings are already unicode in Java. If you just want to know whether the first character is uppercase, you can use `Character.isUpperCase(theString.charAt(0))`.

Comment: @yshavit: Thanks a lot man..! Will surely try that. But for the time being charAt idea of Razib has done my job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try this -

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];

String str = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

System.out.println(str);
```

for more detail you can see [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/unicode.html) tutorial

and for checking the first character you my use str.CharAt(0)

Comment: Thanks a lot..! The last idea of using charAt really made it. Thankyou very much..!