# String replace function not working in android

Tags: java, android

I used the following code to replace occurrence of '\' but its not working.

```
msg="\uD83D\uDE0A";
msg=msg.replace("\\", "|");
```

I spent a lot of time in Google. But didn't find any solution.

Also tried

```
msg="\uD83D\uDE0A";
msg=msg.replace("\", "|");
```

Comment: `msg="\uD83D\uDE0A";` doesn't actually contain any backslashes. The `\u####` gets compiled into a [unicode character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode)

Comment: ya  its a unicode of a laughing smiley. But is there any options to do as mentioned in the question?

Comment: What are you trying to do actually -- replace the smileys with a pipe character, or something else?

Comment: @MickMnemonic i want to send the unicode of smiley to my web url, but when it reaches there it missing the \. Thats why am trying to change it with |.

Comment: if you can't control the input you have to get back original string before replace .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700333/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character

Comment: @FastSnail pls check the above comment. Hope you will understand my problem.

Comment: @JarishJose i'm not families about web url  .can't you send msg directly ?

Comment: @FastSnail am sending msg as url arguments.

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java

Answer (score 4):

The `msg` string defined must also use an escape character like this:

```
msg="\\uD83D\\uDE0A";
msg=msg.replace("\\", "|");
```

That code will work and it will result in: `|uD83D|uDE0A`

Comment: i cant controll the input.

Comment: what if we want to do with same input mentioned in question ?

Comment: @JarishJose plz read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700333/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the unicode integer value of a unicode character, you can do something like this:

```
String.format("\\u%04X", ch);
```

(or use `"|"` instead of `"\\"` if you prefer).

You could go through each character in the string and convert it to a literal string like `"|u####"` if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get the unicode representation of a string. For that you can use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14817912/2775450).

```
private static String escapeNonAscii(String str) {

  StringBuilder retStr = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    int cp = Character.codePointAt(str, i);
    int charCount = Character.charCount(cp);
    if (charCount > 1) {
      i += charCount - 1; // 2.
      if (i >= str.length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("truncated unexpectedly");
      }
    }

    if (cp < 128) {
      retStr.appendCodePoint(cp);
    } else {
      retStr.append(String.format("\\u%x", cp));
    }
  }
  return retStr.toString();
}
```

This will give you the unicode value as a String which you can then replace as you like.